# Another application is sending on my Url params How can i recieve it in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I have a Core project on which I am working in angular 7. I am working on another pay application where I send client params and after that, that other application makes payments and after that application posts in my Core project's URL some params. I want to receive these params. how is this possible in angular?

Comment: What is meant with client param?

Comment: you can try using `query` parameters

Comment: You need to use a technique where the server can inform the client about events. In your scenario (ASP .NET Core) I would recommend [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: What is the URL/param that the other app is hitting? Is it hitting the Angular page directly, or goes through some webhook on your core project?

Comment: its just JSON body with 1 string param . Other application is calling my angular url where he will post this body . I want to just recieve this body and  then to call my controller and send this body. This is i dont know from where they will post . They just post in my Url  this json body.

Comment: Can you confirm whether it's a query param or JSON request body with one property? You are using both words interchangeably, but they are not.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to them using the queryParams from the route.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params);
      });
  }
```

Comment: I will try now this

Comment: i guess it works it worked on get now i will try on post

Comment: Fitted your requirements?